# Why are K8s pods stuck 'Terminating' for over 100mins

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an AWS EKS cluster that runs Istio, Karpenter, AWS EBS CSI driver, AWS node termination handler and our services.

We keep getting pods stuck in a Terminating state and nodes being tainted as `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule` and `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute`.

I have been unable to resolve these issues and need some guidance.

I seem to be unable to retrieve any container logs once the pod gets into a Terminating state. Also if I run:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n status-ns
NAME                          READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
status-api-69cdd64fbf-gc5cz   2/2     Running       0          177m
status-api-69cdd64fbf-tdt8q   2/2     Terminating   0          3h38m
```

But if I try and run this as formatted output, either json or yaml then both containers are marked as 'Running':

```
$ kubectl get pods -n status-ns  -o json | jq '.items[].status.phase'
"Running"
"Running"
```

All the pods that are stuck in a 'Terminating' state seem to be attached to the tainted node, but as above I am unable to get any logs for these.

These pods remain in this state and the node is not terminated unless I manually force delete all the pods

```
kubectl delete pod status-api-69cdd64fbf-tdt8q --grace-period=0 --force -n status-ns
```

1. Why would the node(s) be given these taints and why are the pods not being drained and successfully terminated?
2. Where can I find some useful logs to debug this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The kind of problem you describe occurs when kubelet has problems and can't communicate with the apiserver.

As you point out all affected pods are on the same node. That node has some issues and kubelet failed or at least can not talk to the apiserver. The last known status of the pods is that they were in Terminating and since the apiserver didn't get any new status updates on the pods, the pods stay in that status (when in reality the pods are probably already evicted). Same goes for logs.

So what probably happened is that the node had problems and became not reachable, it got tainted and was drained. But since kubelet doesn't respond the drain can not succeed, keeping the pods in Terminating and blocking the node from being removed from the cluster. Force deleting all pods resolves that lock.